# Will std::optional be a trivially copyable type if the contained type is a trivially copyable type

Tags: c++, c++17

If the type T in a std::optional is a trivially copyable type will the std::optional be trivially copyable. I ask as I would like to use it in an atomic, so is the following valid for some trivially copyable type T

```
std::atomic<std::optional<T>>
```

Comment: I cannot think of a reason why this couldn't be the case, other than wanting to make the implementation easier.

Comment: A potential reason why you wouldn't want `std::optional` to be trivially copyable would be if T is a very large (trivially copyable) type, you wouldn't want to copy it if it doesn't have to

Comment: @vu1p3n0x That doesn't make sense. `std::optional` isn't allowed to use dynamic allocation. If you have to copy it, you have to copy it.

Comment: @T.C. I know that, my point is if `std::optional` used 1 byte of overhead and T is 1024 bytes large, would you want it to copy all 1025 bytes every single time, or would you rather it only copy 1 byte if it doesn't contain a T and copy all 1025 if it does. personally I'd rather it be efficient about it.

Answer (score 13):

The copy constructor is specified as:

> `optional(const optional<T>& rhs);`
>   3 *Requires:* `is_copy_constructible_v<T>` is `true`.
>   4 *Effects:* If `rhs` contains a value, initializes the contained value as if direct-non-list-initializing an object of type `T` with the expression `*rhs`.
>   5 *Postcondition:* `bool(rhs) == bool(*this)`.
>   6 *Throws:* Any exception thrown by the selected constructor of `T`.

Nothing here *requires* that the `optional` be trivially copyable, but by the as-if rule, nothing here prevents an implementation from choosing to do so. In the libstdc++ implementation for instance, `optional<T>` is not trivially copyable for any `T`.

The only explicit discussion of triviality is that if `T` is trivially destructible, then `optional<T>` shall also be trivially destructible.

Comment: "Trivially copyable" is different from "has a trival copy constructor".

Comment: @T.C. Doesn't the former require the latter? (or for the copy constructor to be deleted, which is... odd).

Comment: Yes. Depends on what point you want to make, I guess. "This isn't required to be trivially copyable" or "it can be trivially copyable if an implementation wants to support it". For the latter you need to survey everything. For the former one is enough.